# hide div after a scroll position in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a novice web developer and am developing a blog website.

**Code Function -**
I have a floating pagination bar near the bottom of the screen. I want to hide this pagination bar when the visitor reaches near the footer.

**My code and what I've tried so far-**

```js
var footerPos = document.querySelector("footer").offsetTop;
var partOfScreen = screen.height * 0.08;
var pointToHide = footerPos - screen.height + partOfScreen;

console.log(`footerPos- ${footerPos} ; pointToHide- ${pointToHide} ; screen.height - ${screen.height}`);

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.scrollY > pointToHide) {
    document.getElementById("pagination").style.transform = "scale(0)";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pagination").style.transform = "scale(1)";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination pagination-rounded justify-content-center" id="pagination" style="
              position: fixed;
              bottom: 4vh;

              transform: scale(1); 
    /*this is the property which should change to - scale(0) - on scroll*/

              margin: 0 auto;
              z-index: 1000;
              transition: all 0.2s, transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 1, 2);
          ">

  <li class="page-item" style="border-radius: 50px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);">
    <a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="window.history.back()" style="border-radius: 55px;">
      <i class="int-arrow-left"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="page-item active" style="border-radius: 50px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);">
    <a class="page-link" href="#">1 </a>
  </li>

  <li class="page-item" style="border-radius: 50px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);">
    <a class="page-link" href="https://www.zealforgood.com/test-categories?index=9" style="border-radius: 55px;">
      <i class="int-arrow-right"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

In the above `<script>`

I get the footer's position from the top

Subtract some part of the screen's height from the above value <footer's position> (to add some offset).

I create a `window.onscroll()` function with an `if` statement to hide the element, once the `scrollY` position is more than the above value.

[You can see this code live on this website's source](https://www.zealforgood.com/test-categories)

I've tried making many changes so far, but couldn't get this to work.
Can somebody help me in where I'm coding it wrong.

I'm not familiar with jQuery, please help me in plain JavaScript guys.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly https://vq6qo.csb.app/.

Answer (score 1):

basically I think your code is OK. You didn't put a footer element in the code snippet you gave here and the snippet doesn't work perhaps because of this but I extracted the code you gave, added a footer and a load of scrollable text and it worked, albeit without all the fancy CSS styling.

However, when I went to the website you gave I could see it didn't work.

What seems to be the problem is that other parts of the code are also setting event listeners on scroll. If you go to dev tools in your browser and look at Event listeners you can see there are 4. If you put say a console.log into your bit of the code in test-categories it never gets there.

However, if you REMOVE the first event listener listed (which is in jquery) then your code works and as you scroll down the page the pagination list disappears as you near the footer.

I'm afraid I know nothing about jquery and with only minified code in the source I can't see where/why this eventlistener gets set.

I would have just commented on your question as I haven't found you a full answer for you, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation to make a comment.

Anyway, hope this eventlistener stuff points in a useful direction for you.